# Shortcut Precedence in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am advised that I can use the shortcut `Ctrl + ;` in Google Sheets to insert the current date. However, I have `Sogou Input` installed on my machine and this shortcut is also bonded to the clipboard functionality in that app, and pressing this shortcut would show me the clipboard, without performing the date insertion in my Google sheet.

I am not able to remove this shortcut from the settings of `Sogou Input`. I wish to set a priority that `Chrome (or whichever browser I use for Google Sheets) > Sogou` for this shortcut. Is it possible?

Comment: (1) There's no "Ubuntu 20.02" (2) your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu

Comment: What is your "another app" that appears to steal that shortcut, and what function does it there?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yea sorry, my bad, I meant 20.04. Thank you and do you know where should I ask for help with this issue?

Comment: @vanadium The other app is `Sogou Input`. I followed here for installation - https://sourceexample.com/article/en/9190d5fa09a3e3775a495e3a73d90e9b/ When I press `Ctrl + ;`, the `Sogou Input` app would show me a clipboard asking me which item I want to copy to the destination.

Comment: Add that information to your question - use "edit". OK, it is that application that installs the keybinding. If you cannot change that shortcut there, you will not be able to change: keybindings defined by applications do not make it in the Gnome Keyboard settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be possible. Shortcut keys are defined either global for the desktop, or specific for the application. Global keys take precedence over application specific keys: when you hit a shortcut key, it is first evaluated for global definitions, and if there is none, then it is passed to the application for handling.

The application you installed defined <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> as a global key, which conflicts with a key you want to use in Google Sheets. The only way to resolve that conflict is to change one of the shortcut definitions. If the application does not expose a way to do so, then it may not be possible without editing source code.

Comment: Got it. Thanks vanadium and I have also modified my original question!

Comment: Your question is indeed crystal clear now, although I already grasped your point before your edit.